# ng-bind-html strips elements attributes

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to interpolate a string that contains some markup in a template.

In the controller:
`$scope.message = "Hello moto <a ui-sref='home.test'>click</a>";`

Template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="message.text"></div>
```

which renders as:

```
<div ng-bind-html="message.text" <div="" class="ng-binding">Hello moto <a>click</a></div>
```

Trying to use the following filter does not help either; the text is simpy escaped for either of the commented choices:

```
angular.module('test-filters', ['ngSanitize'])
    .filter('safe', function($sce) {
            return function(val) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
                //return $sce.trustAsUrl(val);
                //return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
            };
    });
```

How can I interpolate my string without escaping it nor stripping attributes?

Edit: Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/H4O16KgS0mWtpGRvW1Es?p=preview (updated with sylwester's version that has reference to ngSanitize

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker example (http://plnkr.co) ?

Comment: @mfirry just edited the original post

Comment: Can you try <div>{{message}}</div> in your template

Comment: @vgSefa does the same thing as `<li> {{ message }} </li>`. Still updated the plunkr though.

Comment: How did you try to use the filter? `ng-bind-html` will try to make a safe to use version of whatever its given, so you'll have to make sure you're using the `$sce.trustAsHtml` correctly

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let have a look here http://jsbin.com/faxopipe/1/edit it is sorted now. 
It didn't work because there was another directive inside a tag 'ui-sref', 
so you have to use $sce service.

in your js please add method:

```
 $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
```

and in view :

```
<p ng-bind-html="to_trusted(message)"></p>
```

Comment: If we say trustAsHtml, How do we prevent XSS ?

Comment: implementing as a filter (rather than scope function) works nicely too.

Comment: Thanks for this. We can make this even simpler – `$scope.to_trusted = $sce.trustAsHtml;`

Answer (score 4):

In scenario where you are using ui.router path you must need to use **$compile** in combination with **$sce** for your dynamic html so that **ui-sref** work properly. If you don't do that you'll just see a Link which actually do not work.

e.g  `<span> Hello moto <a ui-sref='home.test'> Link </a> </span>`

```
//You must need to add boundary conditions, this is just for demonstration
$scope.to_trusted = function(someHTML) {
    var compiledVal = $compile(someHTML)($scope);
    var compiledHTML = compiledVal[0].outerHTML;
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(compiledHTML);
}
```

And you use like this,

```
<p ng-bind-html="to_trusted(message)"></p>
```

**Note that** your message has to be a valid HTML starting from `"<"` so if you pass a non HTML to $compile you'll get **jqlite** error. I used `<span>` to handle your case.

Answer (score 0):

You missed reference to angular-sanitize.js and you have inject it as well to angular.app

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
```

the simplest option in to bind html is **ng-bind-html**  :

```
<li>link ng-html-bind <div ng-bind-html="message"></div></li>
```

please see [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4O16KgS0mWtpGRvW1Es)

Comment: ah yes I did miss the reference to `angular-sanitize.js` in the plunker.  
None of the results end up being unescaped with all properties preserved. The closest one is the "link ng-bind-html" line but it's rendering as `<a>click me</a>`, not `<a ui-sref="home.test"></a>` so your doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Very old post at this point, but there were a couple of errors in the last `<li>`element in the plnkr - the div should read: `<div ng-bind-html="message|safe">` (fixed incorrect `ng-html-bind` directive, and removed `filter:` from the expression.