# Unable to get the custom attribute value dynamically in angular ng-bind

Tags: angularjs

I want to use `ng-bind-html` inside the attribute of element. But how can I use it in angular?

I tried the following:

```
<span data-link="ng-html-bind='<u.link>'" data-id="{{u.id}}">name</span>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24181365

Comment: actually the application is not fully in angular. the is one external jquery file which read value from data-link  attribute.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to do here, or what you are having trouble with.

Comment: do you want to assign some html value to the data-link attribute ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 yes