# summernote - resized image showing without resize in html

Tags: jquery, angularjs, summernote

I am using angular-summernote.

When I try to resize an image using summernotes option, it is being resized in the editor but when I render that html somewhere, original one is being shown but not the resized one.

Any idea what I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with summernote--the answer here worked for me:
[ng-bind-html strips elements attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178316/ng-bind-html-strips-elements-attributes)

From sylwester's answer:

in your js please add method:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
```

and in view :

```
<p ng-bind-html="to_trusted(message)"></p>
```

Don't forget to inject the $sce service to your controller.

Edit: node XSS will also strip the style tags if you are using it, so check that as well.